# Why are Android emulators even-numbered?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This question is just for curiosity. When I run "adb devices", it shows -

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554  device
emulator-5556  device
emulator-5558  device
...
```

I would like to know why the numbers are all even - why doesn't it increment by 1 ? And, why is it always 5554 for the first emulator? Is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: The answer you need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308929/why-android-emulators-are-numbered-like-5554/7308979#7308979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the odd number must be free and will be reserved for ADB.

You can see it in the official document :
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

[image]